# Porting D3.js to other languages

Tags: svg, visualization, d3.js

I am looking to use D3.js in a c++ application, where using js isn't feasible for a variety of reasons.

What elements of js/svg/css are being relied on in the code that would not be easily substituted with svg/vector type drawing functions from a c++ library.

Where am I likely to run into difficulty?

Comment: I can't fathom how this could even be posible. D3 relies on the dynamically typed features of Javascript and makes extensive use of functional programming. Whatever roadblock preventing you from using javascript is surely less of a challenge than porting D3 to C++

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful information. Do you know if the functional programming aspects are pervasive or is it more limited to specific parts if I were to pick and choose specific parts that I need for my project?  Are there any alternatives you might recommend?

Comment: In addition to Duopixel's comments I'd like to point out that even if D3 was implemented in a language very similar to C++, you would still have to port several thousand lines of code. And you would have to provide many things that you get for free in Javascript (i.e. everything that browsers give you like a DOM tree, SVG support). Then there are platform-specific issues to consider. Unless you can commit considerable resources, porting D3 to C++ is not an option at all.

Comment: As the others have mentioned it is probably easier tot just use an existing c++ graphics library. It isn't an option to include webkit for example in your application? If Java is an option you could have a look at processing.org

Answer (score 6):

As some people have commented, beyond D3 relying on some of the features of Javascript (not just syntactically, but even more so with respect to the nature of the language itself) - it also depends on the DOM and some means of interpreting SVG markup -- all of which is included in a browser environment.

Have you considered the [R programming language](http://www.r-project.org/)?  I've always been under the impression that one of the voids D3 fills is providing some of the same data-driven approach to visualization that is supported in R, but just in a browser environment.

Now - that's not to say that R can do everything that D3 can do or vice versa - but there is a lot of overlap as far as visualization is concerned and depending on the nature of your needs - R might be just what you're looking for.  And if that's the case, there is a great library called [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) and another called [rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) that aim to provide integration of C++ in R and R in C++.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is easy to port in C++... don't let commoners tell you otherwise.
Clipp can parse javascript , so you don't even need to port D3.js totally.

People are confusing functionnal programming and C++ syntax, you can cover all type of coding style in C++ ( either with Spirit, Phoenix, boost:lambda, expressive or remote dynamic libray ).